# To check if a chain with $n$ links can be "folded" into a size at most $L$

Tags: algorithms, graphs, asymptotics, dynamic-programming

Given a chain of $n$ links, each of length $a_1, a_2,..a_n$, where each $a_i$ is a positive integer. $L$ defines the length of the "folded" chain. More formally, we want to decide whether there exists a $t \in [0, L]$ and $s_1,...,s_n \in \{-1, +1\}$ such that $t + \sum_{i=1}^j(s_ia_i)\in[0,L]$ for all $j\in\{0,..,n\}$.

For example, given $a_1 = 5, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 7, a_4 = 2, a_5 = 8,$ and $L = 9$ a possible solution could be $5+1-7-2+8$ such that the entire chain is contained within a space of $9$ units.

We need to provide an $O(nL)$ time algorithm to decide if the chain can be folded or not.

My approach: 
I tried a couple of different approaches:

- Greedy algorithm: starting with the first link, check if it is greater than $L$, if yes then subtract $(s = -1)$ the second link from the first link. If it is still greater than $L$, the repeat. If it was not greater than $L$ initially, then add the second link to the first. This approach failed.
- Tree approach: For every link, we can have $s=1$ or $s=-1$, this gives us $2^n$ possible arrangements. We can create a binary tree of size (layers) $n$ from this. But this method won't work due to the sheer size of the tree.

Any hints or guidance is appreciated.

I was also thinking that if $L$ is not given, is there a way to determine $L$ such that it is the best folding possible?

Comment: You have tried greedy algorithm and simple brute force. Have you tried dynamic-programming, the only approach that you have tagged the question with?

Comment: I suggest studying the material at https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info and then try applying it to your situation.

Comment: Additionally, one can show that this problem is NP-Compete by reducing from 2-partition. Therefore, it is unlikely that it has a polynomial solution. (Note that $O(nL)$ is only pseudo-polynomial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux of the problem is to identify when we can extend a chain $t, s_1a_1, \cdots, s_ka_k$ to a longer chain?

Let $m$ be the length of that chain, i.e., $m= t +\sum_{i=1}^ks_ia_i$. If $m+a_{k+1}\in [0,L]$, then we can extend it with $+a_{k+1}$. If $m-a_{k+1}\in [0,L]$, then we can extend it with $-a_{k+1}$. Otherwise, the chain cannot be extended.

#### An approach by dynamic programming.

Create a $(n+1)$-row by $(L+1)$-column table $F$ (shorthand for **f**oldable). All entries of $F$ are False initially. $F[k][j]$ will be true if there is a chain made from $a_1,\cdots, a_k$ with length $j$ and within space $L$.

Set $F[0][j]=\text{True}$ for all $j$, $0\le j\le L$. According to the analysis above, $F[k+1][j]$ is true in two cases.

- $j-a_{k+1}\in [0,L]$ and $F[k][j-a_{k+1}]$ true.
- $j+a_{k+1}\in [0,L]$ and $F[k][j+a_{k+1}]$ true.

In other words, we can fill all values at row $F[k+1]$ if we know all values at row $F[k]$.

If $F[n][j]$ becomes True in the end for any $j$, then we return yes. Otherwise, return no.

#### Explanation on 5, 1, 7, 2, 8

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
t 0  T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T
5 1  T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T
1 2  T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T   T
7 3  T   T   T                   T   T   T
2 4  T       T   T   T   T   T   T       T
8 5  T                           T
```

The fourth row $F[3]$ corresponds to chains of the form $t$, $\pm5$, $\pm1$, $\pm7$. Their lengths can only be 0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9. Now if you add $\pm2$ to them, you can get lengths

```
     2,  3, 4, 9, 10, 11 (for +2)
    -2, -1, 0, 5,  6, 7  (for -2)
```

So the possible lengths of chains of the form $t$, $\pm5$, $\pm1$, $\pm7$, $\pm2$ are 2, 3, 4, 9, 0, 5, 6, 7, which correspond to row $F[4]$.

#### How to find the smallest realizable $L$?

A binary search on integers in [a_1, 2M-1] should be a nice way to find the answer, where $M$ is the maximum value of $a_i$s. Binary search is feasible since, if $L$ is realizable, values larger than $L$ are realizable too.

#### Exercises

**Exercise 1.** (One minute or less) Show that the smallest realizable $L$ is at most $2M-1$, where $M$ is the largest of $a_i$s.

**Exercise 2.** Adjust the algorithm if $s_i\in\{-2,-1,1,2\}$ for all $i$ instead of $\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Makes sense, but what I don't understand is why the rows and columns are n+1 and j+1. Wouldn't we just n rows and j columns?

Comment: $F[0]$ is the first row, which corresponds to the chain that has $t$ only. $F[n]$ is the last row, which corresponds to the chain that contains $s_na_n$. So there are $n+1$ rows.

Comment: For each chain, its length can be $0, 1, 2, \cdots, L$. There are $L+1$ values.

Comment: Could you also illustrate the algorithm you gave using the example I mentioned?  I was thinking the first row would be {0, T, T, T, T} here the first element is 0 because we are not adding or subtracting 5 from itself. The second row would be {T, 0, T, T, T} as adding 1 to all the other elements doesnt exceed our L. The third row is where I am confused. When encountering the 7, how do we treat it? what would the third row look like? I know my understanding is flawed, sorry about that.

Comment: Please come to http://collabedit.com/pqagc for a chat.